# How do you apply a full-height flex background color solution to work on all devices, including iPads?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I found a solution to make background (colors) fill full-height on my Linux PC. It works in both Chrome and Firefox. With my windows 2:1 it works in both IE browsers and FF and Chrome. It also works on my Android phone.

Including bootstrap 3, the relevant CSS:

```
.row-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-content {
  padding: 20px 20px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%; /* forces background color to fill to bottom */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row row-flex">

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-ss-6">
    <div class="col-content colour-1">
      <h3>First column</h3>
      <p>This one has a bit longer content</p>
      <p>This one has a bit longer content</p>
      <p>This one has a bit longer content</p>
      <p>This one has a bit longer content</p>
      <p>This one has a bit longer content</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-ss-6">
    <div class="col-content colour-2">
      <h3>Second column</h3>
      <p>Normal content.</p>
      <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div> <!-- row -->
```

Demo: https://www.dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/iPad/equal-height.html

iPad Info: iOS: 13.3.1 and Safari: 13.0.5

[image: iPad]

Comment: It looks OK on my iPad (IOS 14.2). Could you show an image of what you see that is wrong perhaps?

Comment: I added a screen capture. I bought the iPad primarily for testing, don't use it much - no messing with default configuration of fonts or anything else that might affect the display.

Comment: Thanks, I’ve now seen the problem on an old iPad mini, IOS 9.3.2, (only it is worse, with boxes not all becoming one height). So we are looking for some feature that was corrected between versions 9 and 14+. Which IOS version do you have?

Comment: I added the iPad info to the post - 13.3.1. If I understand correctly, flex box is supported for Safari beginning with 6.1.8. What you describe sounds like earlier Safari. I checked caniuse.com. I'm not too concerned about support of flexbox, but yes to the inconsistency of this technique working in all browsers and devices (assuming supported). I am not excited about trying to write a hack to make this work for the iPad. Is there a better, more universal background fill solution perhaps? Other ideas?

Comment: Yes as far as I can see caniuse says everything you are using is supported in IOS 13, it seems to be <=11 where some/various things are different.

Comment: Just check Chrome on my iPad - similar failure meaning this probably eliminates the browser.

Comment: Chrome and Safari on IOS are basically the same

Answer (score 0):

Flex Box does not seem to be a good solution because of its apparent lack of support, consistency by Apple iPads. I'm sure there are other solutions available however the first batch which I found didn't apply well because they were targeting layouts, primarily fixed width. I also tested Grid, somewhat similar to Flex Box but it didn't work well with bootstrap rows and columns - or perhaps there was something missing from the reads.

As a result I took a step back in time and reverted to employing the matchHeight library, https://brm.io/jquery-match-height/. I modified it just a bit to get to work well with bootstrap, and tested it on the iPad, to perfection. See the working demo at https://www.dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/iPad/equal-height-columns.html . All you do is include the matchHeight javascript library, add an initialization script and add a corresponding style to each row and column.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="matchheight/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="matchheight/jquery.matchHeight.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    $(function() {
      var byRow = $('body').hasClass('matchheight');
      $('.matchheight-row').each(function() {
        $(this).children('.matchheight-column').matchHeight({
          byRow: byRow
        });
      });
    });
  })();
</script>

<body class='matchheight'>
  <div class="row -row-flex matchheight-row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-ss-6 matchheight-column">
    ...
```

You could probably move the matchheight class out of body and into a containing div.